# Looking for ColorChooser.jar

Tags: java, swing, jar

I am beginner, and I need `ColorChooser.jar`.

Does it come with Netbeans or I need to download it? (if I need to download it where I can find it?)

Thanks

Comment: try http://www.findjar.com/

Comment: Try with Google, questions about off-site resources are off-topic on SO.

Comment: It comes with netbeans find it in components

Comment: where is the components

Comment: @Adriano: Why is this "off-topic"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It comes with NetBeans. It is buried in the installation directory. Search for the file in your operating system if you have NetBeans installed.

Comment: ok thanks for help I found it

Comment: @mussdroid "_please vote my topic_". Without words.